# Statistically back-calculating: Markov Chain?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, operations-research

I would like to calculate the value of bacteria on 4 surfaces $i=\{1..4\}$. A person touches some of those 4 surfaces at random and a count is made on their finger after each surface contact ($x_i$).

Someone lost the bacteria count ($x_i$) after each surface but I do know the total count (X) on a persons's finger after they've touched a number of surfaces. I also know which ones and in which order.

What I know:

1. Final bacteria count on a person's finger: $X$
2. Transfer efficiency from surface to finger: $PT_i=\displaystyle \frac{\text{Finger contact area}}{\text{Area of surface}_i}\frac{1}{\gamma_i}$ where $\gamma$ is a surface dependent constant.
3. The number of times the person touched a particular surface: $h_i$.

If I had surface counts $C_i$, the summation of bacteria is linear: 
ie
$\begin{eqnarray}
h_1C_1PT_1&=&x_1\\
h_2C_2PT_2&=&x_2\\
\vdots\quad &=& \quad \vdots\\
h_iC_iPT_i&=&x_i
\end{eqnarray}$

such that summing over all surfaces $i$ the total count x is: $\displaystyle \sum_i h_iC_iPT_i=\sum_i x_i=X$.

Can I back calculate $C_i$, without $x_i$ even statistically or probabilistically?
Best regards.

Comment: Did each subject touch all 4 surfaces, or did some touch some surfaces more than once? If the latter, simultaneous equations spring to mind.

Comment: Does the finger contact area in your expression for $PT_i$ vary with each touch?

Comment: @Michelle The subject(s) don't necessarily touch all four but any surface can be touched a number of times.

Comment: @jbowman It could do.

Comment: Do you have a measure of length of touch for each trial?

Comment: @Michelle Yes that's part of $\gamma_i$, but let's assume for now, that it's constant for each surface.  What do you think so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've only dipped the top of my toe into operations research, so I welcome comments on this suggestion.  Basically, you have what I think is an optimization problem (trying to get the most accurate estimates for each surface). I think you have a problem that can be solved through solving as a series of simultaneous equations using either linear or nonlinear programming. This falls squarely into operations research, and is outside my area of expertise.

I don't think you can use a Markov Chain process for this as you don't have transitional probabilities.

Comment: Interesting.  Could you advise as to what part of linear programming this might come under?  I do actually have the transition probabilities but they're only a guess at best as I didn't observe the process.  Would they help do you think?  Thanks and best regards

Comment: On reflection I don't have the transition probabilities between surfaces. Only the probability of touching surface $i$

Comment: Sorry, I can't be of more help with the LP/NLP as I have no experience or qualifications in that area. I'm hoping for an OR professional to chime in.